# Embedding Python and adding C functions to the interpreter

Tags: c++, python, c, function-pointers, embedding

I'm currently writing an applications that embedds the python interpreter. The idea is to have the program call user specified scripts on certain events in the program. I managed this part but now I want the scripts to be able to call functions in my program.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include "python.h"


static PyObject* myTest(PyObject* self,PyObject *args)
{
    return Py_BuildValue("s","123456789");
}

static PyMethodDef myMethods[] = {{"myTest",myTest},{NULL,NULL}};

int main()
{

    Py_Initialize();
    Py_InitModule("PROGRAM",myMethods);

    PyRun_SimpleString("print PROGRAM.myTest()");


    Py_Finalize();
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind that function to some module, see http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html#extending-embedded-python

Edit:
Basicly your code should work. Whats not working?

Comment: Haha, a single PyRun_SimpleString("import PROGRAM"); was all that needed to get it to work!